Can't upload private key using app signing key
I have flow the all process to generate the the key and it's successfully generated but can't upload the key

I have try with both file (.zip/.pem)
java -jar C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AndroOutput\pepk.jar --keystore C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AndroOutput\AndroUp.jks --alias AndroUp --output  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AndroOutput\AndroUp.pem --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a

I think you need to ask for help from Google play submission team.
